# Flutter IOS app icon doesn't chage (on background layout)

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, appicon

I am using flutter_launcher_icons to set app icon. here is the pubspec.yaml:

```
  android: true
  ios: true
  remove_alpha_ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
```

it actually changed all icons: notification,appicon, etc. only one icon doesn't change. when you scroll from bottom of iphone, it will show opened application. and there is icons of them as well. it is not changed my case. I will attach image below

[image]

Comment: i did all the stuffs: clean, pub get, pod install, re-installing etc. but didn't work.
only when i build it in another simulator it worked. i guess there was something with simulator itself

Answer (score 1):

Go on the iOs folder and right-click on that:
Select the Open in Xcode item

Check this items:

[image]

and also

[image]

if it's not still okay, delete the asset file and add new asset file:(make sure that have a copy from previous asset file)

[image]

[image]

and set (image, icon, etc) it again. and make sure and check the first image I sent the Asset file name.

note: "in **XCode 15** the App icon has just **one** icon"

finally, check it on your device.

Answer (score 0):

In the iOS, the app icon, the app switcher icon & the notification icon are all the same. Try uninstalling & re-installing the app. Maybe it glitched there.

Comment: i did all the stuffs: clean, pub get, pod install, re-installing etc. but didn't work.
only when i build it in another simulator it worked. i guess there was something with simulator itself

Comment: Try different simulator devices & acknowledge me here. Is it working over there or not?

Comment: So, it was an issue with your simulator. Try resetting it.

Answer (score 0):

May one of these can help

- Clean and Rebuild:

> Execute `flutter clean`.
>
> Rebuild and reinstall your app.

- Ensure All Icons are Updated:

Check the ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/ directory.
If any icons are old, replace manually and rebuild.

- Verify Info.plist:

Ensure it references the correct icon set:

```
<key>CFBundleIconName</key>
<string>AppIcon</string>
```

- Uninstall and Reinstall: Remove the app from your iPhone and reinstall.

Comment: i did all the stuffs: clean, pub get, pod install, re-installing etc. but didn't work.
only when i build it in another simulator it worked. i guess there was something with simulator itself